# I frequently get hard review audits in the Close Votes review queue

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues, review-audits

I find it nearly impossible to consistently pass audits in the Close Votes review queue, even when I'm really dialed in / focused on them and spend a good chunk of time reviewing. Following a failure, the problem is less that the system is stopping me from reviewing more questions but that I'm just generally discouraged at this point.

Can I just ask: Are these audits legitimately as hard as they seem to me? Should I simply stop reviewing close votes?

Comment: have you examples of where you went wrong and why?

Comment: Some examples would be nice.  Audits generally should be able to be spotted fairly quick.  It is generally not rocket surgery ;-)

Comment: @Hayt It's hard to remember which examples. But I didn't come here to impune the these questions. I just wanted to know if others (as NathanOliver suggests) are getting them right 90+ % of the time? If so, maybe this just isn't for me

Comment: @ControlAltDel I mean something somewhere is wrong if you fail the tests a lot. Which may be either your interpretation on the guidelines (where an example could help explaining you what is expected/ where the mismatch lies) or the test having some issue with not being clear in their way somehow.

Comment: If you are in any doubt about a review you can always just Skip. Or you can click on 'link' and look at the full question. Even after 40k close votes I still get the occasional one wrong, but mostly you get to recognize the audits fairly easily.

Comment: Thank you all for your input on this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally you should be able to spot an audit.  There are always going to be bad audits (hopefully this will change and they are more the exception than the norm), but the regular audits should not take too much processing power to figure out if the question is good or bad (audits test for both in the close vote queue).

That said you can do a couple things to help yourself out.  If you want to see all close vote types then I suggest you use the filter and filter it to tags that you know.  This will make it a lot easier for you to tell when you need to have some technical experience to judge the question.  If you do not want to just patrol your own tags then I suggest you start with close vote reasons that are easier to deal with.  Unclear is a good reason to start with as it is much easier to determine no matter what language the OP is using.  Once you start getting comfortable then you can start adding more reasons or tags.

Another important tip is **Do not be afraid to skip**.  If you are unsure if it needs to be closed or stay open, just skip it.  If it is an audit nothing bad will happen and if it is not then it passes it to other users to decide.  It will not remove it from the queue.